# Sequence of tenses (He lived)

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> I met my father in August. He lived in a different prefecture, so it had been  a while.

I wrote this sentence but my English teacher said that I had to use “lives” instead of “lived”. I think “lived” is correct. Please tell me your opinions.

Comment: It depends. What's your father's status now? He *lived* would mean the past which means it'd be then a different context.

Comment: He still lives there.

Answer (score 1):

> I met my father in August. He lived in a different prefecture, so it
>   had been a while.

People could answer this with 
"oh where does he live now?"

because 'lived' is in the past, something has changed

you could continue that with

> He lived in a different prefecture first then moved to a different
>   country

Comment: Or he passed away.

Comment: @Smock he can't have died as the son has just met him

Comment: Not necessarily - it could be December and the father died in September. *I met my father in August. He lived in a different prefecture, so it had been a while. He then passed away in September, so that was the last time I saw him*

Comment: he could also have been abducted by aliens

Comment: The place of residence he *lives* in would still be the prefecture though. He either moves or dies to be *lived*

Answer (score 1):

It depends, that what you mean by saying live, if your father has changed the address then you can use lived, but if he has not moved then you would say lives as he is still there.

Comment: He still lives there. Then should I use “lives”? But a person who always wears glasses can “wore” glasses in the past, can’t he? Like “he wore glasses but it looked like sunglasses.”